# invoke amazon alexa through program API. is it possible?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

changing the alexa wake up intents. instead of alexa, I want to invoke it through a program API?

Amazon voice service API is available to invoke by variety of means? For example, my application program (web/mobile) should make an api call to invoke alexa and other possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are asking if it is possible to cause an Alexa custom skill to start talking upon receiving an API call instead of in response to a user saying "Alexa, ...".

If that is your question, then the answer is "No, that is not currently possible". However, last month Amazon announced that "[Notifications for Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/8cc45487-d5fb-413b-b6c7-eeea4794d10c/amazon-announces-notifications-for-alexa-feature-is-coming-soon-sign-up-to-stay-tuned)" is coming soon. This may enable this sort of capability. We'll have to wait and see.

If that isn't your question, please restate your question, and possibly provide an example of what you are trying to do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, That is exactly my question and I am sorry for being vague in question. I will update it.

Comment: Based off of their announcement, it looks like the "Notification for Alexa" thing only allows a notification (light, small blip of noise, etc) to be sent to the Alexa. It doesn't sound like it will allow an entire skill to be invoked like the question is asking.